# Spark: Get elements of an RDD based on the elements of an array in another RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

In Spark Scala framework, I have an RDD, `rdd1`, in which each element represents a single element of a matrix `A`:

`val rdd1 = dist.map{case (((x,y),z,v)) => ((x,y),v)}`

`x` represents the row,
`y` represents the column and
`v` represents the value in matrix `A`.

I also have another RDD, `rdd2`, in the form of `RDD[index, Array[(x, y)]]` where the array in each element represents the set of elements of the matrix `A`, which are stored in `rdd1`, needed for the specific `index` represented in that element.

Now what I need to do, is get the values of the matrix `A` elements for each `index`, preserving all data including `index`, `(x,y)` and `v`. What would be a good approach in doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your question boils down to:

```
val valuesRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
//((x, y), v)
  ((0, 0), 5.5),            
  ((1, 0), 7.7)
))

val indicesRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
//(index, Array[(x, y)])
  (123, Array((0, 0), (1, 0))) 
))
```

And you want to merge these RDDs to get all values `(index, (x, y), v)`, in this case, `(123, (0,0), 5.5)` and `(123, (1,0), 7.7)` ?

You can definitely do this using `join`, since both RDDs have a common column `(x, y)`, but since one of them actually has an `Array[(x, y)]` you'd have to explode that into a set of rows first:

```
val explodedIndices = indicesRdd.flatMap{case (index, coords: Array[(Int, Int)]) => coords.map{case (x, y) => (index, (x, y))}}
// Each row exploded into multiple rows (index, (x, y))

val keyedIndices = explodedIndices.keyBy{case (index, (x, y)) => (x, y)}
// Each row keyed by the coordinates (x, y)

val keyedValues = valuesRdd.keyBy{case ((x, y), v) => (x, y)}
// Each row keyed by the coordinates (x, y)

// Because we have common keys, we can join!
val joined = keyedIndices.join(keyedValues)
```

Comment: Thank you. It issues an error regarding the `_` used in the flatMap statement: `missing parameter of type for expanded function...`

Comment: Ok. It worked with a little modification: `val explodedIndices = qual.flatMap{case (index, coords: Array[(Long, Long)]) => coords.map{case(x,y) => (index, (x, y))}}`. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Fixed the answer, I hadn't actually tried to run it.